# C Socket code works within LAN but not over WAN? Connection refused?

Tags: c, sockets, dns, posix, nat

I've been working on a connect 4 game that contains both the client and server code in my main function for a TCP connection.I'm unable to connect over the internet. I've tried running my client code on a laptop that isn't on my LAN specifying my LAN's public IP and the desired port number. However,keep getting a connection refused as my perror message when connect fails.

//client code

```
if(argc == 3){
        turn = CLIENT;
        int status, client_sockfd;
        struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    
        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

        if((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &res)) != 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));       
            exit(1);
        }   

        if((client_sockfd = socket(res -> ai_family, res -> ai_socktype, res -> ai_protocol)) == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "socket creation error: %s\n", gai_strerror(client_sockfd));        
            exit(1);
        }

        
        if((connect(client_sockfd, res -> ai_addr, res -> ai_addrlen)) == -1){
            perror("cannot connect");       
            exit(1);
        }
        
            freeaddrinfo(res); //free res structure 

            //Start of Game: Client 
            recv(client_sockfd, player1, 25, 0);
            printf("Player 2, enter your name:\n");
            fgets(player2, sizeof(player2), stdin);
            send(client_sockfd, player2, 25, 0); 
            sock = client_sockfd;

        }
```

//server network code

```
else{
         turn = SERVER;
         int server_sockfd;
         printf("Setting up the game\n");

        //server port 
        if(argc == 2)
            myport = argv[1];
        else
            myport = "12345";
        
        int status, sock_fd;
        int opt = 1;
        struct addrinfo  hints, *res;
        struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
        socklen_t addr_size;
        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints)); //make sure hints is empty
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; //ipv6 or ipv4 doesn't matter
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; //require TCP stream sockets
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
        
        //load res adderinfo struct 
        if((status = getaddrinfo(NULL, myport, &hints, &res)) != 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));       
            exit(1);
            }
        
        
        //create socket with res
        if((sock_fd = socket(res -> ai_family, res -> ai_socktype, res -> ai_protocol)) == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "socket creation error: %s\n", gai_strerror(sock_fd));      
            exit(1);
            }

        //reuseable socket
        if(setsockopt(sock_fd,SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt)) == -1){
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
            }
        //bind socket for use 
        if((bind(sock_fd, res -> ai_addr, res-> ai_addrlen)) == -1){
            perror("binding fail");
            exit(1);
            }
        
        
        //listen with a backlog of 5 
        listen(sock_fd, 5);

        addr_size = sizeof(their_addr);
        if((server_sockfd = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_size)) == -1){
            perror("accepting failure");
            exit(1);
            }

        freeaddrinfo(res); //free res structure 
        
        //Start of Game: Server 
        printf("Player 1, please enter your name:\n");  
        fgets(player1, sizeof(player1), stdin);
        send(server_sockfd, player1, 25, 0); 
        recv(server_sockfd, player2, 25, 0);
        sock = server_sockfd;   
    }
```

Any thoughts? From my understanding, as the client, my packet should reach the server's gateway and NAT should use my destination port  to redirect my messages to the server?

Comment: It could be a firewall issue. If a firewall blocks a connection, you will probably get the error code for "connection refused".

Comment: Did you setup **port forwarding** on your router? When a server is behind a NAT, you need to explicitly map the NAT's WAN IP:port to the server's LAN IP:Port in order for the server to receive incoming connections from the outside world

Comment: Also, you are using `AF_UNSPEC` on both ends. That means the resulting `addrinfo` list from `getaddrinfo()` MAY contain multiple entries, some for IPv4, some for IPv6, depending on DNS, configurations, etc.  You should loop through the entire list, not just use the 1st entry only. A server could listen on multiple interfaces at a time.  A client could connect to multiple IPs until one of them is successful.

Comment: @RemyLebeau. It seems like the port forwarding wasn't setup. Once i did that everything worked out. Thanks!